# Why is my array empty at the function that receives it in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mongodb

I got data back from a fetch to my python API. With the data, I created a new array of json strings. I can see the array contains 2 entries if I do a console.log(array). When I pass that array into a function of a child element, the array is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code.
My call to the python api that returns data:

```
        var myArray = [];
    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';
    const apiUrl = baseUrl + '/api/load_data';
    fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-Api-Key': 'react_main',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080/',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-type, Authorization',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then( res => {
            res.map(function(dataObj) {
                    const data = {
                        id: dataObj['id'],
                        imgLocation: {backgroundImage: dataObj['image']},
                        city: dataObj['city'],
                        state: dataObj['state']
                    }
                    myArray.push(data);
                }
            )

            console.log(myArray);
        });
```

I then pass it further down to function below:

```
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import React from "react";

    class HomePage extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                cards: [],
            }
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';
            const apiUrl = baseUrl + '/api/load';

            fetch(apiUrl, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'X-Api-Key': 'react_main',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080/',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-type, Authorization',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-type': 'application/json',
                },
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then( res => {
                    res.map(function(cardObj) {
                            const card = {
                                title: cardObj['title'],
                                imgLocation: {backgroundImage: cardObj['image']},
                                city: cardObj['city'],
                                state: cardObj['state'],
                                url: cardObj['url'],
                            }
                            this.setState(prevState => ({cards: [...prevState.cards, card]}))
                        }
                    )
                }).catch((e) => console.log(`Error! ${e.message}`));
        }

        render() {
            var divStyle = {
                clear: 'both',
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            };

            return(
                <div>
                    <MainComponents.HeaderElement />
                    <div className="gray-bg-wrapper">
                        <section>
                            <h1 className="section__title">New Cards</h1>
                            <h2 className="section__subtitle">Most recent Cards added</h2>
                            <div className="cards">
                                <MainComponents.CardElement listCards={this.state.cards}
                                />
                            </div>

                            <div style={divStyle}>
                                <a href="/browse/" className="btn btn--cta cards__more-btn">Browse Cards</a>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                    <MainComponents.FooterElement />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

In the MainComponents.CardElement function. listData is empty:

```
    export var CardElement = function(props) {
        return(
            props.listCards.map(function (item) {
                return (
                    <div className="card" key={item.title.replace(' ', '_')}>
                        <div className="exp-card">
                            <a className="nostyle" target="_blank" href={item.url}>
                                <div className="exp-card-image" style={item.imgLocation}>
                                    <div className="card-fader"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="exp-card-info">
                                    <div className="exp-card-detail">
                                        <div className="exp-card-title">{item.title}
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="exp-card-location">
                                            <i className="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                                            <span className="neighborhood">{item.city}, {item.state}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        )
    }
    CardElement.propTypes = {
        listCards: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    }
```

Comment: Are you not storing `myArray` in state?

Comment: Not storing array in state may be the case. `fetch` is async code, so during firrst run it just sends request to backend and returns. `myArray` will be empty. Then React will render your component with empty `myArray`. Then response will come and `myArray` will be filled with data. But React will not know if it should render again. Storing `myArray` in `state` may solve you problem. But to answer exactly it's better to look at full code.

Comment: Can you share the full component code

Comment: You're right @go_diego. I wasn't setting state. When I did that, the component rendered... but because I was setting state inside of a render, it was infinitely looping. So I pulled all the code out and put it in a ComponentDidMount() function and now it's no longer rendering :(. But as least I know it has to do with the state.

Comment: If you still need help with this we can definitely help if you post the full component.

Comment: @go_diego I added more of the code for context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Changing my componentDidMount() function to the following made it work. Thank you to everyone that noticed I wasn't setting state.

```
    componentDidMount(){
        const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';
        const apiUrl = baseUrl + '/api/load';
        let currentComponent = this;

        fetch(apiUrl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X-Api-Key': 'react_main',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080/',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-type, Authorization',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then( res => {
                let arrCards = [];
                res.map(function(cardObj) {
                        const card = {
                            title: cardObj['title'],
                            imgLocation: {backgroundImage: cardObj['image']},
                            url: cardObj['url'],
                            city: cardObj['city'],
                            state: cardObj['state'],
                        }
                        arrCards.push(card);
                        currentComponent.setState(function(){
                            return {
                                cards: arrCards
                            }
                        })
                    }
                )
            }).catch((e) => console.log(`Error! ${e.message}`));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at async call. I thought you are putting all of these code in render() method. The async method (promise chain) will got delay in response. In other words, your render will be execute before your list got values. To make it work, you need to move the result to a state and render base on this. Basically, render() methods will be invoked twice. Initially with empty list, and second time after your state got updated.